# Parse String To Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I have a field formatted as "32.49|33|30|100|20.5|21|18|100|33.39|33|30|100|1.4".  I am trying to split it out as 13 different columns. This query works somewhat, but when I try to run it in Power BI, the "Cross Apply" join fails, as well as any attempt I have made to pivot the data to columns.

```
SELECT 
DataMessage.MessageDate
, DataMessage.Data
, Sensor.SensorID
, CSNet.CSNetID
, Sensor.SensorName
, Application.ApplicationName
, value

FROM 
 [corp--monnit1\monnitsql].[Enterprise1].[dbo].[DataMessage] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    [corp--monnit1\monnitsql].[Enterprise1].[dbo].[Sensor] ON DataMessage.SensorID = Sensor.SensorID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                    [corp--monnit1\monnitsql].[Enterprise1].[dbo].[CSNet] ON Sensor.CSNetID = CSNet.CSNetID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    [corp--monnit1\monnitsql].[Enterprise1].[dbo].[Application] ON Sensor.ApplicationID = Application.ApplicationID
CROSS APPLY
STRING_SPLIT(DataMessage.Data,'|')
WHERE
CHARINDEX('|',DataMessage.Data)>0
AND Application.ApplicationName ='ThreePhaseCurrentMeter500' 
AND Csnet.CSNetID = 10 
AND DataMessage.MessageDate > '03/29/2023' 
AND DataMessage.Data != '0'
```

I am hoping to find a solution that will work well with Power BI and will split the delimited field into columns.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021127) - 14.0.2047.8 (X64)   Jan 25 2023 08:29:55   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following JSON based solution. It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('32.49|33|30|100|20.5|21|18|100|33.39|33|30|100|1.4');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.ID
    , Col1 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[0]')
    , Col2 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[1]')
    , Col3 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[2]')
    , Col4 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[3]')
    , Col5 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[4]') 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(tokens,'json'),'|','","') + '"]')) AS t1(j);
```

**Output**

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32.49 | 33 | 30 | 100 | 20.5 |

In your real life query please make the following modification:

- Replace

  CROSS APPLY
  STRING_SPLIT(DataMessage.Data,'|')

with the following:

```
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(DataMessage.Data,'json'),'|','","') + '"]')) AS t1(j)
```

- Add to the `SELECT` clause:

  Col1 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[0]')
  , Col2 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[1]')
  , Col3 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[2]')
  , Col4 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[3]')
  , Col5 = JSON_VALUE(j,'$[4]')

Comment: Thank you!  That works as written, but I am inexperienced enough to not know how to use it in the existing query.  Can you explain please?